# What am I missing? Java Optional<Long> get returns Object

Tags: java, types

I have a getter in Java which returns an Optional but when I try to call .get() on it and assign it to a Long as below my compiler and IDE throws an error calling it a type mismatch, claiming it is returning an Object.  This seems straight forward, I've worked with Optionals in the past and never have had this issue.  I'm not sure why it would matter but the asset class implements an interface which has getDuration() as part of it, returning an Optional.  Does anyone know what is wrong here (getDuration() returns Optional)?

Edit: Added full implementation with generics to clarify

```
Long duration = assetResponse.getAsset().getDuration().get();
```

Response object class:

```
 public class AssetResponse() {
    private AssetInterface asset;
    
    public AssetInterface getAsset() {
        return asset;
    }
}
```

Interface class:

```
public interface AssetInterface<T> {

  @JsonIgnore
  Optional<Long> getDuration();

  List<T> getAssetTagList();
}
```

Implementation class:

```
public Asset implements AssetInterface<AssetV1> {
   
    private Optional<Long> duration;
    private List<AssetV1> assetTags;

    @Override
    public List<AssetV1> getAssetTagList() {
        return assetTags;
    }

    public setDuration(Optional<Long> duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Long> getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Why? Is duration really an optional attribute of an asset?

Comment: Just a tip, Duration is a strong type in java and a better type than using Long for whatever unit you are using. If I was using your API, I would be annoyed if getDuration did not return a Duration. If you insist on "primitive obsession" then please specify the unit, e.g. getMillis

Comment: @user207421 inconsequential, I personally hate how this site is always why why why. It doesn't matter. Even if you discover that it matters to the asker, it usually results in an answer that doesn't even answer the original question, so we are stuck with a bad Google result

Comment: @Novaterata +1 on the "Why?" response.  I didn't write the AdInterface class or the implementing class I'm just trying to figure out why it get doesn't appear to be returning the type that it should be.

Comment: @Novaterata It's a perfectly reasonable question. Very often the answer is that you don't want to do it anyway.

Comment: If you want a `Long`: declare the field a nullable `Long`, not an `Optional`, and in your getter wrap into an `OptionalLong`, not an `Optional<Long>`.

Comment: The sequence of edits to this post go to show: A minimal example is fine. Only make sure it actually demonstrates the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Your code does not actually demonstrate your complaint.

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors, and mission constructor. Before posting here, get your example code to compile.

Comment: `AssetV1` is undefined.

Comment: After much cleaning, [your code works](https://ideone.com/rtpH37). Your `Optional<Long>` is indeed recognized as a `Optional<Long>` when calling `assetResponse.getAsset().getDuration()`.

Comment: @BasilBourque It "works" with an implicit unchecked cast from `Optional` to `Optional<Long>` (which I'm surprised compiles). If you tried to do `Long value = assetResponse.getAsset().getDuration().get()` instead, you'd get a compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to know for sure without seeing more code. But I see two plausible ways this could happen:

1. The type signature for `getDuration` declares that it returns `Optional` rather than `Optional<Long>`.
2. The type signature for `getDuration` returns `Optional<T>` where `T` is a type declared on the class (so, like `Asset<T>`), and you've declared `asset` as `Asset asset = ...` rather than `Asset<Long> asset = ...`.

Comment: Tried to add a sample of the code above.  Neither of these cases is applicable.  The interface class does use generics (not shown in the example) but not on the getDuration method

Comment: @thurmc Are there **any** raw types involved? (in your real code)

Comment: @Slaw yes!  I updated the original question to show the raw types as it more accurately is represented in the code.

Comment: @thurmc Your update shows `getAsset` is returning the _raw type_ `AssetInterface`. That means **all generics** of `AssetInterface` are erased in that context, meaning the return type of `getDuration()` becomes the raw type `Optional`. Since `Optional::get` returns `T`, and the erasure of `T` is `Object` in this case, you see the return type of calling `get` as `Object`.

Comment: @thurmc If you can, change the return type of `getAsset` to `AssetInterface<?>`.

Comment: @Slaw that makes sense.  Thank you for your help.  I knew that raw type was going to be an issue, unfortunately I didn't write it I just have to work with it.

Comment: @thurmc You could try casting to `AssetInterface<?>` instead. Might give you an "unchecked cast" warning, not sure (though you could just suppress it if it does occur).

Comment: @Slaw I'll try that and see if it works